# Strange error message while syncing Project tasks to Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2010, synchronization, ms-project

Using new Project 2010 feature "Sync to Tasks List" get following message-

Microsoft Project
Unable to write information for task "XXX" to SharePoint.
Ensure "XXX" contains valid data and try again.

Any ideas on the root cause -what exactly could be wrong with the task data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the root cause is, but I had this same error and was able to resolve it.  I was using Project 2010 and Office 2007 when I was getting the error.  I upgraded to office 2010 and then the error went away.  Not sure why, but everything syncs between Project and SharePoint just fine now.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.